# Reverse the characters of a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to reverse the words in a string. Consider a string 'My name is abc'. The expected output should be 'cba si eman yM'. But I am getting the output as 'cba si emanyM'. There's something wrong in the final whitespace character. Can someone help me?

I a trying to reverse the string from the end
Here's the code

```
void reverse(String str)
{
    int i = str.length() - 1;
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    for(int j = arr.length - 1; j > 0; j--){
        if(arr[j] == ' '){
          swap(arr,i, j);
            i = j - 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println( new String(arr).toString());
}

void swap(char[] s,int start, int end){
    while(start > end){
        char temp = s[start];
       s[start] = s[end];
         s[end] = temp; 
         start --;
         end++;
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str =  "My name is abc";
    ReversWords r = new ReversWords();
    r.reverse(str);
}
```

Comment: Should `while(start > end){` be `while(start < end){` perhaps?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use a stack?

Comment: `System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).reverse());`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am trying to reverse it from end

Comment: @MichaelAlbers There's no specific reason, I am just trying to do it using strings

Comment: Oh I see.  That's a very confusing approach.  Well,  then shouldn't `j` start from `i-1`, not `arr.length-1`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am having problem with the last whitespace character. there should be gap between first two characters

Comment: The words seem to be a distraction. What you seem to want (from the example you posted) is to reverse all the letters of a string. Why not simply do that and avoid any logic that treats spaces as special?

Comment: Unless your expected out is `abc is name My`, then the title of this post should be "reverse the characters in a string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, your desired sample output:

> cba si eman yM

suggests that you don't want to reverse each word, but simply reverse the entire string.

However, let's assume that this is wrong and, as your title says, you want to reverse the letters in each word, leaving the words in their original order, so the output you want is:

> yM eman si cba

When I run your code, the output I get is:

> Myeman si cba

The main problem is that you are only reversing words when they are preceded by a space. This test fails for the first word. In `reverse`, after you exit the loop you need to swap from 0 through `i` before you print the result.

You have a further problem in that the spaces are ending up at the trailing end of the swapped words, which is why the space between "My" and "name" seems to have disappeared. In other words, if you printed "_" in place of each space, your current code's output is:

> Myeman_si_cba_

To fix that, don't include the space when you call `swap`. The `reverse` method should then look like this:

```
void reverse(String str) {
    int i = str.length() - 1;
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    for(int j = arr.length - 2; j > 0; j--){
        if(arr[j] == ' '){
          swap(arr,i, j + 1);
            i = j - 1;
        }
    }
    swap(arr, i, 0);
    System.out.println( new String(arr).toString());
}
```

Output:

> yM eman si cba

Answer (score 1):

You could have just done this

```
    String s = "My name is abc";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
    sb.reverse();
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output: cba si eman yM

Comment: Most likely, this is homework. And such "detours" will not help then.

Comment: Haha, they need to get some punishment in their classroom to use a single function instead of algorithm first, they will not post such questions again.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop those unwanted conditions and make it [simple](http://ideone.com/4IZ1wX):

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "My name is abc";
    System.out.println(str); // My name is abc
    String rev = "";
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; 0 <= i; i--) {
      rev += str.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(rev); // cba si eman yM
  }
}
```